# Mystery 'additional notification' banner on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

*Sorry about the low-quality of this bug report. I can't reproduce on demand, but will keep an eye out for it.*

I logged in on an iPhone, and received a light blue notification banner at the top informing me that I had received a Nice Answer badge. I dismissed it and continued browsing.

A short while later, another light blue notification banner appears, with some wording I have forgotten, but which basically said 'There's an additional notification to display." I thought that was odd - rather than tell me that there is another notification, why not just show it?  But I selected it to see the notification, and it disappeared.

It popped up again shortly afterwards, and I repeated the experience.

I think it may have happened a third time, and as I dismissed it, I thought "Odd. Next time it happens, I should take a screenshot and report the bug."

Naturally, it didn't happen again.

Logging in with a real browser, I can't see anything in my history that might have triggered a notification except the single badge.

Comment: I'm skeptical of your claims...

Comment: It's always awkward when people introduced to some field of interest makes exactly the same sad jokes that you did when *you* were introduce to that field. I've never worked out the best response...

Comment: It's okay, Programmers has certainly been the butt of its share of jokes.

Answer (score 1):

This has been obsoleted by the new top bar. Closing as completed.